# Xdebug not loaded on XAMPP in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xampp, xdebug, ubuntu-16.04

Xdebug with XAMPP in Ubuntu 16.04
I Install xammp for Ubuntu 
I install xdebug as in Tailored Installation Instructions.
No errors
but Xdebug not loaded
I'm stuck.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Take a look for this tutorial.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370395/xdebug-for-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/38436870#38436870 especially the config part can help you